# How to access ejabberd admin api via HTTP

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-api

I m getting token now.

http://IP:5280/oauth/authorization_token?response_type=token&client_id=armsprime&redirect_uri=http://www.razrcorp.com/&scope=get_roster+connected_users+sasl_auth

http://www.redirectdomain.com/?access_token=CZ750oz9yPWLvI9p0k5fDlzFfJP4Iu9m&token_type=bearer&expires_in=31536000&scope=get_roster%20connected_users%20sasl_auth&state

But now if try to access using postman

Api url: http://ipaddress:5280/api/get_roster

Header:
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:Bearer reJqgKFPCyM1OcFmy8XrK9YdRh2UdYxV
//X-Admin:true

Body:
{
}

Response: 400 Bad Request

Can someone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, this API call requires a post with user and server as parameters in JSON.

Comment: Yes Mickael i doing the same. Please verify if i m missing something.

Comment: Request eg: curl -v -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer pyywX4LeUXRI86zWp5oxL3UKMaMKnGLj" http://IP:5280/api/get_roster -d '[]'

Comment: Response Eg: Trying IP....
TCP_NODELAY set
Connected to IP (IP) port 5280 (#0)
POST /api/get_roster HTTP/1.1
Host: IP:5280
User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
Accept: */*
Authorization: Bearer pyywX4LeUXRI86zWp5oxL3UKMaMKnGLj
Content-Length: 2
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
* upload completely sent off: 2 out of 2 bytes
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 168
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type
<?xml version='1.0'?> *Connection #0 to host IP left intact<h1>400 Bad Request</h1>%

Comment: your data are empty (see -d). You are not posting the needed parameters.